# Grouping and filtering data

Tags: python, pandas

Dataframe:

```
Protein   Peptide   Mean intensity  
A1        AAB       4,54             
A1        ABB       5,56             
A1        ABB       4,67                       
A1        AAB       5,67             
A1        ABC       5,67            
A2        ABB       4,64             
A2        AAB       4,54             
A2        ABB       5,56             
A2        ABC       4,67                        
A2        ABC       5,67
```

But i need to find for every protein top 2 (most frequent) peptides so the output would be for A1 :

```
Protein    Peptide   Mean intensity   
A1         AAB       4,54 + 5.67 / 2
           ABB       5.56 + 4.67 / 2
A2         ABB       7,42
           ABC       5,17
```

So the problem is it needs to stay as a dataframe.

Comment: Cal you please explain the calculation how you get to your desired result? And what does a value like `4,54 + 5.67 / 2` mean? Very wild guess: distribution with 4.54 as mean and 5.67 as FWHM or `5.67/2` as standard deviation?

Comment: No I just meant that it calculates for protein A1 peptide AAB ( in first table it has two values, and just calculating the means of these two peptide values) so adding AAB mean values and dividing by how many AAB are. Mean of mean intensity for the peptide.

Comment: Okay, right, got it, but I still don't get how you get a value of 7.42 for A2/ABB . Is that a typo? Because if you just want the mean value for each protein/peptide combination yout can just call `df.groupby(['Protein', 'Peptide']).mean()`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we can perform a groupby/apply operation to obtain the Protein/Peptide pairs with the two largest Peptide counts for each Protein:

```
counts = (df.groupby(['Protein'])['Peptide']
            .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().nlargest(2)))
counts = counts[counts >= 2]
counts = counts.to_frame()
#                  counts
# Protein Peptide        
# A1      AAB           2
#         ABB           2
# A2      ABB           2
#         ABC           2
```

Now we can merge the original DataFrame, `df` with `counts`, by joining on the columns of `df` and the index of `counts`.
Using an inner join guarantees that only those Protein/Peptide pairs which are present in both `df` and `counts` show up in `result`:

```
result = pd.merge(df, counts, left_on=['Protein', 'Peptide'], right_index=True,
                  how='inner')

#   Protein Peptide  Mean intensity  counts
# 0      A1     AAB            4.54       2
# 3      A1     AAB            5.67       2
# 1      A1     ABB            5.56       2
# 2      A1     ABB            4.67       2
# 5      A2     ABB            4.64       2
# 7      A2     ABB            5.56       2
# 8      A2     ABC            4.67       2
# 9      A2     ABC            5.67       2
```

Now it is easy to perform the desired `groupby/mean` operation:

```
result = result.groupby(['Protein', 'Peptide'])['Mean intensity'].mean()
```

---

So putting it all together,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s{2,}')

counts = (df.groupby(['Protein'])['Peptide']
            .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().nlargest(2)))
counts = counts[counts >= 2]
counts = counts.to_frame()
result = pd.merge(df, counts, left_on=['Protein', 'Peptide'], right_index=True,
                  how='inner')
result = result.groupby(['Protein', 'Peptide'])['Mean intensity'].mean()
result = result.reset_index()
print(result)
```

yields

```
  Protein Peptide  Mean intensity
0      A1     AAB           5.105
1      A1     ABB           5.115
2      A2     ABB           5.100
3      A2     ABC           5.170
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for! Although I didn't mention that I also have to use only proteins that have at least 2 different peptides (as some have only one). So hard when you're a biologist and forced to use python :D

Comment: Selecting the protein which have at least 2 different peptides can be done with `count = count[count >= 2]`. I've edited the post above to show what I mean.