# Filtering, grouping data

Tags: python, pandas

```
PROT      PEP       SD  
1        XXX      4,54             
1        XXX      5,56             
1        XXY      4,67                       
1        XXZ      5,67             
1        XXY      5,67  
1        XXX      5,68          
2        XXW      4,64             
2        XXZ      4,54             
2        XXW      5,56             
2        XXX      4,67                        
2        XXX      5,67
```

I need to figure out a way of filtering data by prot and pep but keeping only pep where there is more than 1 pep for prot -> and then filter again so for every pep values only 2 with the highest SD remain (and sum these two / divide by 2)

Output for PROT1:

```
PROT    PEP   SD
1       XXX   5.56+5.68 /2
        XXY   4.67 + 5.67 /2
```

I think this may be the way if I figure out what to put after lambda x: so it takes three top values, right now it's giving me one top value index.

```
counts = (df6.groupby(['PROT','PEP])['SD']
        .apply(lambda x: x.idxmax()))
```

Comment: How is this different from [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636451/grouping-and-filtering-data)? Also, it is common courtesy to accept answers to your questions that answered your question, there will be an empty tick mark at the top left of the answers

Comment: It is different though, the other one I was doing wrong myself. I tried to modify it but it didn't work out. The other one was- top two pep but this one is all pep (well all that occur more than once) but top 3 SD values not top 3 PEP values. Just figured the accepting thing literally 30 seconds before I saw your comment. Sorry.

Comment: No worries, no idea why someone downvoted but perhaps you need to show what you've tried and why your efforts doesn't produce what you specifically want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be tempted to do this in a single pass:

```
In [11]: g = df.groupby(['PROT', 'PEP'])

In [12]: g['SD'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if len(x) < 2 else (x.nlargest(2).sum() / 2))
Out[12]:
PROT  PEP
1     XXX    5.62
      XXY    5.17
      XXZ     NaN
2     XXW    5.10
      XXX    5.17
      XXZ     NaN
Name: SD, dtype: float64
```

and then drop the NaN.

---

> filtering data by prot and pep but keeping only pep where there is more than 1 pep for prot

Use groupby filter:

```
In [21]: g = df.groupby(['PROT', 'PEP'])

In [22]: g.filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 2)
Out[22]:
    PROT  PEP    SD
0      1  XXX  4.54
1      1  XXX  5.56
2      1  XXY  4.67
4      1  XXY  5.67
5      1  XXX  5.68
6      2  XXW  4.64
8      2  XXW  5.56
9      2  XXX  4.67
10     2  XXX  5.67
```

> filter again so for every pep values only 2 with the highest SD remain (and sum these two / divide by 2)

You can use nlargest, on the second pass (but this starts to get messy).

```
In [31]: (g.filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 2)
           .groupby(['PROT', 'PEP'])['SD']
           .nlargest(2)
           .groupby(level=[0, 1])
           .sum() / 2)
Out[31]:
PROT  PEP
1     XXX    5.62
      XXY    5.17
2     XXW    5.10
      XXX    5.17
dtype: float64
```

I think we can agree the top methods is clearer (and more efficient!).

Comment: Thanks it does the trick! But before it was a dataframe and now if I want to group only by protein again as g.groupby('PROT').mean() it won't work, it's not in table format anymore.

Comment: Either use `.groupby(level='PROT')` or `.reset_index()` to make it into a DataFrame.